# Why does `user.has_perm(Model, obj)` return False although `user.has_perm(Model)` returns True?

Tags: django, django-authentication

In a Django project and application just created with `django-admin startproject` and `./manage.py startapp`, I've created this model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Then I run this code with `./manage.py shell`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.models import Book

myuser = User.objects.create_user(username="myuser")
myuser.user_permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(codename="change_book"))

mybook = Book(author="Joe Author")
mybook.save()

myuser.has_perm("myapp.change_book"))  # The result is True
myuser.has_perm("myapp.change_book", mybook))  # The result is False
```

Why is this? The user *does* have permission to edit `mybook`, doesn't he? How is `has_perm()` supposed to work? Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `has_perm()` API is designed to work with both model-level permissions (second parameter is `None`) and object-level permissions. It's up to individual [authentication backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends), however, to determine what to support.

In the case of Django's default `ModelBackend` there is [no support for object-level permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-object-permissions):

> Django’s permission framework has a foundation for object permissions, though there is no implementation for it in the core. That means that checking for object permissions will always return `False`.

This is also noted in the [`ModelBackend` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend).

Note that the backend must return `False` here since the results from individual backends are, in essence, OR'ed together. If this backend returned `True` it wouldn't be possible to respect the finer-grained results from other backends.

And there *are* backends that implement object-level permissions, [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) being perhaps the best known. See how it documents [`has_perm()`](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/guardian.backends.html):

> Main difference between Django's `ModelBackend` is that we can pass `obj` instance here.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any standard practice on how to interpret these permissions? For example, for a user to be able to edit an object, should he have both model-level AND object-level permissions? Or only one of these? Or only the second? The admin only supports model-level, and `django-rules` subclasses it to support object-level. I guess it's the app (such as django-rules or whatever we are developing) that decides how to interpret?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides: Right, it really depends on the specific authentication backends and how they're designed to be used. It's not really a pluggable system, because you have to know what those rules are project-wide. For example, as you've seen, if you're calling `has_perm()` you have to know whether or not your project is using object-level permissions to know whether or not to pass the second argument.